# Eclipse Java autocomplete has white text on white background

Tags: eclipse, ide

I'm using Eclipse for Windows and autocomplete is giving me white text on white background. Is there a setting I can change to fix this? I've looked around but there doesn't seem to be an answer on the internet. Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried restoring the defaults in the `General` > `Appearance` > `Colors and Fonts` and `General` > `Editors` > `Text Editors` preferences?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I tried look it up there but didn't succeed. Did you managed to change? - @blahdiblah

Comment: restoring `Text Editors`  to default worked. But don't know how it happened at my first use of STS suite.

Answer (score 8):

In "Window>Preferences"

then "General>Appearance"

make sure "Use mixed fonts and colors for labels" is turned on.

then  ">Colors and Fonts>basic"

"Content Assist Background/Foreground Colors" choose anything you like

Comment: This worked but partially. The highlighted text still has white background although now the text is at least visible. Changing the background color changes the whole color for the dialogue which shows all autocomplete suggesstions. I only have  this issue on my office laptop with windows 10. Otherwise my home desktop with both windows 10 and ubuntu doesn't have this issue. Is there any further customization possible?